# How to quit python interpreter with code?

Tags: python, interpreter

I want to quit interpreter when `-i` is passed in. eg

```
> python -i test.py
yeah
SystemExit
>>>
```

I want to quit interpreter. my test.py

```
import sys
print 'yeah'
sys.tracebacklimit = 0
sys.exit()
```

I have tried `exit()` and `quit()`, but I am still in the interpreter. The reason I want to do this is because I have a script from mayapy( autodesk maya python interpreter ), which launches like this
`mayapy -i myscript.py [args]`, I want to quit interpreter when `--help` is passed as argument, but it always stays in interpreter because `-i` is passed in.

Is there a way to have the same effect as `ctrl+d` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke the `os._exit` call.

```
import os
os._exit(0)
```